# Passing a variadic function as argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic

Consider this working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <typename... Args>
void foo (Args&&... args) {
    const auto v = {args...};
    for (auto x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';     std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename> struct Foo;

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct Foo<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template <typename Container>
    static void execute (const Container& v) {
        foo(v[Is]...);
    }
};

template <std::size_t N>
void fooArray (const std::array<int, N>& a) {
    Foo<std::make_index_sequence<N>>::execute(a);
}

int main() {
    fooArray<6>({0,1,2,3,4,5});  // 0 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

I want to now generalize the `Foo` struct like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <typename... Args>
void foo (Args&&... args) {
    const auto v = {args...};
    for (auto x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';     std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename> struct Foo;

template <std::size_t... Is>
struct Foo<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template <typename Container, typename F>  // *** Modified
    static void execute (const Container& v, F f) {
        f(v[Is]...);
    }
};

template <std::size_t N>
void fooArray (const std::array<int, N>& a) {
    Foo<std::make_index_sequence<N>>::execute(a, foo);
}

int main() {
    fooArray<6>({0,1,2,3,4,5});
}
```

But I get a compile error (from GCC 4.9.2) that F cannot be deduced.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: foo is an unresolved method group. You need to pick the correct one with a cast or template arguments before giving it to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is a family of overloads, and so the `foo` is ambiguous.
(even `foo<int, int>` is, as it may have additional type too).

You may force expected type function as follow:

```
template <std::size_t... Is>
struct Foo<std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
    template <typename Container>
    static void execute (const Container& v, void (*f)(decltype(v[Is])&...)) {
        f(v[Is]...);
    }
};
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/QeAyq0)

An alternative is to wrap function `foo` into a class:

```
class FooCaller
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void operator () (Args&&... args) const {
        const auto v = {args...};
        for (auto x : v) std::cout << x << ' ';     std::cout << '\n';
    }

};
```

and keep your implementation:

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/EJ5kz1)

Comment: @ Jarod42  Thanks!  And then generalizing `fooArray` to using `f` instead of `foo`?  It's not quite the same thing, is it?  Well, I tried and it works with your second method, but using your first method?

Comment: @prestokeys: `fooArray` should have a second argument, a function with `N` parameters. That requires some helper to create the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

A template is not a single thing.  You cannot pass a template function as a function or an object.  Now the name of an overload set (say, `foo`) can resolve to a single instance of a template function in particular contexts (where you call it, or convert it to a function pointer), which is probably what fooled you.

If you want to work with an entire overload set as an object, you can approximate it via:

```
struct foo_f{
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)const->
  decltype(foo(std::declval<Args>()...))
  { return foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
```

and now an instance of `foo_f` approximates the overload set of `foo` as a single object.  Pass `foo_f{}` in place of `foo`.

In C++14, alternatively:

```
[](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){return foo(decltype(args)(args)...);}
```

is a lambda that behaves much like `foo_f` above.