# cannot bind variadic function and save to a std::function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, variadic-templates, stdbind

I successfully implemented my own `thread_pool` class where I can submit lambdas that can return any value but can only take zero arguments. I would like to improve it, such that it can work like `std::async`, where one can call it as follows: `std::async(my_function, arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_n)`. As I have it right now it looks as follows:

```
template<typename T>
auto enqueue_task(T&& task) -> std::future<decltype(task())>
{
    auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task())()>>(std::forward<T>(task));
    {
        //some mutex
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mutex(mutex_);
        //The task is added to a queue of std::function<void()>
        tasks_.emplace([=] {(*wrapper)(); });
    }
    has_work_.notify_one();
    return wrapper->get_future();
}
```

My ideal solution would be such, that I can pass arguments to functinons in my `thread_pool` like such:

```
pool.enqueue_task(my_function, arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_n)
```

where `arg_1, ..., arg_n` are the arguments of `my_func`

For this I sucessfully create a function which can take a variadic amount of arguments, but I have not managed to save this function int my std::function queue. I read on this link:
[Passing a variadic function as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233037/passing-a-variadic-function-as-argument) how to achieve my goal by using std::bind. Yet I have not managed to achieve my goal. Here is how I understood it, what turned out not to work:

```
//some function with variadic arguments
template <typename... Args>
void test1(Args&&... args)
{

}

void test2(int a)
{
}

//main method
std::function<void()> a = std::bind(test2, 2) //works
std::function<void()> b = std::bind(test1<int>, 1) //does not work
```

Comment: any reason to use `bind` over a lambda? `b = [](){ test1(1); };` should work.

Comment: `test1<int>` has the signature `void test1(int&& arg)`. Only accepts an rvalue reference.

Comment: You are trying to pass an lvalue of type `int` to the function instantiated from `test1` as `test1(int&&)` which does not work. You might want to change `test1(Args&&...)` to `test1(Args...)`.

Comment: Or use `test1<int&>` instead of `test<int>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::bind` will pass argument as lvalue. From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> the ordinary stored argument arg is passed to the invokable object as lvalue argument

When you specify `test1<int>`, the function becomes `void test1(int&&)`, which cannot accept lvalue.